# Desktop own shell: black screen after ctrl+alt+del

Tags: windows, desktop, kiosk

My Goal is to have a kiosk application on Windows that is launched in fullscreen and that user cannot escape. To do that, I replaced explorer.exe by my_fullscreen_app.exe under `Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Custom user interface`.

Everything works well, but when user press `ctrl+alt+supp` and then `cancel`, the screen becomes black. When I look at the task manager, my_fullscreen_app.exe is processed but not displayed anymore.

How to avoid this problem **without disabling** `ctrl+alt+del` ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the shell application has a few special rights with regards to the GUI. So you could register for a notification when the user unlocks the computer, and make yourself visible (or active) again.

Comment: Does this have to do with System Event Notification Service (SENS) ? Or maybe a task schedule with Taskschd.msc ?